# How do I make a query with CASE statement on WHERE clause on django ORM?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I'm having some troubles trying to make a complex query on Django ORM.
This is the query:

```
SELECT "app_client"."name",
            "app_order"."client_id",
            "app_client"."country",
            (SUM("app_order"."grand_total") - SUM("app_order"."shipping_amount")) AS "total",
            COUNT("app_order"."id") AS "orders",
            SUM("app_order"."total_item_count") AS "products",
            (AVG("app_order"."grand_total") - AVG("app_order"."shipping_amount")) AS "avg",
            SUM("app_order"."shipping_amount") AS "total_shipping"
            FROM "app_order"
                INNER JOIN "app_client" ON ("app_order"."client_id" = "app_client"."id")
                WHERE (NOT (NOT "app_client"."is_active")
                AND "app_order"."created_at" at time zone 'utc' at time zone
                (case WHEN app_client.country = 'CL' THEN 'America/Santiago'
                    WHEN app_client.country = 'CO' then 'America/Bogota'
                    WHEN app_client.country = 'PE' then 'America/Lima'
                    WHEN app_client.country = 'AR' then 'America/Buenos_Aires'
                    else 'GMT'
                END)
                BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59+00:00')
            GROUP BY "app_client"."name", "app_order"."client_id", "app_client"."country"
            ORDER BY "total" DESC;
```

I have this query on the ORM, but I need to add the CASE statement on the WHERE clause.

My ORM query:

```
Order.objects.exclude(client__is_active=False).values('client__name', 'client__pk', 'client__country').filter(created_at__range=(self.request.GET['created_at__gte'], self.request.GET['created_at__lte'])) \
                .annotate(total=Sum('grand_total') - Sum('shipping_amount')) \
                    .annotate(orders=Count('pk')).annotate(products=Sum('total_item_count')) \
                        .annotate(avg=Avg('grand_total') - Avg('shipping_amount')).annotate(total_shipping=Sum('shipping_amount')).order_by('-total')
```

I try to do it using raw method, but it didn't work.
Someone can help me please!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) expression for if/else operations. Since you didn't provided your models code, here's a potential example:

> case WHEN app_client.country = 'CL' THEN 'America/Santiago'

can be translated to Django ORM as:

```
Order.objects.annotate(
        tz=Case(
        When(app_client__country='CL', then=Value('America/Santiago')),
        default=Value('UTC'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```